# am trying to get my local json data through providers am getting an error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

enter image description here
Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(error: any) => void'. Type 'Promise' provides no match for the signature '(error: any): void'.

Comment: share an image of you code or raw code here . i can't understand clearly what problem you have

Comment: Please copy your code here and format it as text instead of linking to a screenshot of your code. It will make it a lot easier for us to understand, evaluate, and help you with.

Comment: Also, your first image is not showing up as a link because it has brackets around the image URL, and your second link doesn’t appear to be referenced within your post, so isn’t being displayed anywhere.